# Does the firefox IDE for selenium export to regular python code using the selenium lib?

Tags: python, selenium

The python selenium lib page has this sample:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.keys import Keys
from time

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.yahoo.com") # Load page
assert browser.title == "Yahoo!"
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("p") # Find the query box
elem.send_keys("selenium" + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(0.2) # Let the page load, will be added to the API
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://seleniumhq.org')]")
except NoSuchElementException:
    assert 0, "can't find seleniumhq"
browser.close()
```

But when I export a saved session from firefox selenium IDE, the python code looks much different:

```
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re

class create_order(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://localhost/")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_create_order(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel.open("/User/LogOn")
        sel.type("UserName", "testuser")
        sel.type("Password", "123")
        sel.click("//input[@value='login']")
        sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
        sel.click("link=Settings")
        sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
        sel.click("//input[@value='Some Link']")
        sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")      
        sel.click("link=Save>")
        sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

is it using a different API?

Comment: What's the other python code?

Comment: the code that the IDE spits out, updated question above.

Answer (score 1):

the first snippet uses the newer WebDriver API.

the second snippet uses the original Selenium 1 API.

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html